# 403 forbidden is returned while executing php curl

Tags: php, curl, zoho

I'm using PHP curl to send data to zoho crm but it is returning "403 forbidden" error. Now the thing is, I am sending multiple xml on that page using a single curl function, when I send data to accounts or potentials, its being sent properly and giving me a success response, but when I try to send data to contacts, it's giving me an error, what I'm trying to say that the same curl is working fine above and giving error in the same file, I mean if there is a  problem with curl why would it be running successful three times but not the fourth time. 
Secondly, when I put that same code in localhost its working fine, which means my xml is also fine, can anybody please help me, I've searched dozens of articles but none of them are of any help, here is the code.

```
<?php
$auth = '************';
//creating new contact
$xml = "<Contacts>
<row no=\"1\">
<FL val=\"First Name\">James</FL>
<FL val=\"Last Name\">Franco</FL>
<FL val=\"Email\">test@test.com</FL>
<FL val=\"Department\">CG</FL>
<FL val=\"Phone\">0000</FL>
<FL val=\"Fax\">99999999</FL>
<FL val=\"Mobile\">99989989</FL>
<FL val=\"Assistant\">John</FL>
</row>
</Contacts>";
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';

$p_true_url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Contacts/insertRecords?";
$p_true_query = "authtoken=" . $auth . "&scope=crmapi&newFormat=1&xmlData=" . $xml . "";

$p_true1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_URL, $p_true_url);
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($p_true1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p_true_query);
$p_true_response = curl_exec($p_true1);
curl_close($p_true1);
print_r($p_true_response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The remote machine might block frequent requests.
use,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'URL'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
```

Comment: if it were issue of blocked frequent requests, then why is it working other 4 times?? in the same page having the same curl...?